# How to delete only one text box when we click a button which is beside particular text box?

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).on("click",".btnnn",function() {
    for(i=0;i<data1.length;i++) {
        if(nam==data1[i].Name) {
           for(j=0;j<data1[i].PhoneNo.length;j++) {
              var text="<br><input type='text' class='append'>";
              $("#textbox"+data1[i].PhoneNo).after(text);
              return false;
           }
        }
    }
});
```

I have appended the textboxes dynamically. How can I delete only the particular text box when I click the particular button which is beside the textbox? Both the text box and button are created dynamically.

I have tried above but all textboxes are removed.

Comment: Please post the code where you are trying to remove the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

You need some sort of way of creating a unique reference between the button and the text box. One possibility using jquery could look like this.

HTML

```
<div>
     <input type='text' class='append'>
     <button>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(this).siblings()
```

You would then be able to reference the text box in the button onclick event using $(this).siblings() and only the textbox located inside that parent div would be found.